# Is it ok to use a plunger on a basement toilet connected to a pump?

Tags: plumbing, basement, toilet

Our basement is below grade of the sewer line, so we have a pump to send waste to the sewer. The pump has a closed well in the floor of the mechanical room.

The toilet in the basement is flushing slowly. I would like to use a plunger to try to clear any presumed clog. I think any force from the plunger would be absorbed by the well, but I want to avoid damaging the pump or the well itself.

Is there any reason to be concerned about using a plunger in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A plunger will not damage your pump. You may have a back flow valve / or check valve to prevent sewage from backing up into the toilet. It is a nasty job but some times the valve needs to be cleaned, it should be accessible. Plunge away it may just clear things up.